# Как настроить IIS для работы Asp.Net Core приложения с MS PowerPoint

Tags: c#, interop, office-interop, powerpoint

У меня есть Asp.Net Core Web Api приложение. Я использую библиотеку Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint для работы с презентациями.

У меня есть код, который открывает презентацию по указанному пути

```
ApplicationClass pptApplication = new ApplicationClass();
        
Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Presentation pptPresentation = pptApplication.Presentations.Open($"C:\\publishApp\\{fileName}", 
      MsoTriState.msoTrue, MsoTriState.msoTrue, MsoTriState.msoFalse);
```

При запуске приложения из visual studio, все работает корректно. Но после того, как я запаблишил приложение в iis веб сервер, я получаю ошибку при открытии презентации. Стек ошибки:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80004005): Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.
   at Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Presentations.Open(String FileName, MsoTriState ReadOnly, MsoTriState Untitled, MsoTriState WithWindow)
   at App.Controllers.Api.FilesController.ConvertSlideToImage(String fileName) in E:\App\Controllers\Api\FilesController.cs:line 180
   at App.Controllers.Api.FilesController.PostUploadFileAsApplication() in E:\App\Controllers\Api\FilesController.cs:line 136
   at lambda_method80(Closure , Object )
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.TaskOfActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, ValueTask`1 actionResultValueTask)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeInnerFilterAsync>g__Awaited|13_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|19_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

Явно проблема с правами доступа к офисным приложениям. Пробовал решение из данной статьи [Как настроить IIS для работы Asp.Net с Ms Office Word и Excel](https://stud-work.ru/kak-nastroit-iis-dlya-raboty-asp-net-s-microsoft-office-word-i-excel) не помогло.

Comment: Вместо абсолютного пути `C:` используйте относительный с `~`

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Моя проблема заключается точно не в пути файла. А в работе с com объектом powerpoint.

Comment: Строка `new ApplicationClass()` выполняется? Падает на строке `pptApplication.Presentations.Open`?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov да, все верно

Comment: Ну значит COM-объект создаётся. / Вы уже попробовали указать правильный путь?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov На всякий случай попробовал последовать Вашему совету и получил путь через _webHostEnvironment.ContentRootPath;  После чего проблема решилась. Я смотрел на стек ошибки и был на 100% уверен, что проблема с COM-объектом. Спасибо!

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Добрый день. Все таки не до конца понимаю проблему. Попробовал на еще одной машине. Вновь получил эту же ошибку на моменте открытия презентации Presentations.Open(). Чтобы убедиться, что файл доступен, перед открытием добавил лог, где проверяю доступен ли файл по данному пути. Файл доступен. Но все равно получаю исключение `string pathForPresentation = $"{path}\\{fileName}"; FileInfo fileInfoPresentation = new FileInfo(pathForPresentation); if (fileInfoPresentation.Exists) Logger.Info($"{path}\\{fileName} - file is available" );`